Can I download the full content of a mainPanel or other ShinyApp panel as an HTML/pdf file?
I am currently building a ShinyApp. It has many tabPanels that can be used to generate various plots and tables.
I also have a Report tabPanel. Here, plots and tables generated on other tabPanels can be added sequentially.
I would like to be able to download the entire contents of the Report main panel with the click of a button. Is this possible? A pre-built module? Unfortunately, I have not found one.
I'd like to have a Save/download report button on the Report panel, which simply saves all the stuff in the Report panel that has been sent there.
I I'm going to paste a very quickly put together bit of nonsense here. The point is that the plot and table are added sequentially to the Report panel. I had a lot of trouble putting this little report download together and it doesn't work very well either. E.g. the DT table does not work.. Is there a simpler solution than this?
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(base64enc)
library(DT)  # For rendering data tables

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Iris Dataset Analysis with Report"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("x_var", "Select X Variable", choices = colnames(iris)[1:4]),
      selectInput("y_var", "Select Y Variable", choices = colnames(iris)[1:4]),
      actionButton("add_plot_to_report", "Add Plot to Report"),
      actionButton("add_table_to_report", "Add Table to Report"),
      textAreaInput("note_input", "Add Note", "", width = "100%", height = "100px"),
      actionButton("add_note_to_report", "Add Note to Report")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Scatter Plot", plotOutput("scatter_plot")),
        tabPanel("Table", DTOutput("data_table")),
        tabPanel("Report",
                 uiOutput("report_content"),
                 downloadButton("download_report", "Download Report")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Reactive values to store report content
  reportContent <- reactiveValues(items = list())
  
  # Render scatter plot
  output$scatter_plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(iris[[input$x_var]], iris[[input$y_var]],
         xlab = input$x_var, ylab = input$y_var,
         main = "Scatter Plot")
  })
  
  # Render data table
  output$data_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris)
  })
  
  # Add scatter plot to the report
  observeEvent(input$add_plot_to_report, {
    plotfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
    png(plotfile)
    plot(iris[[input$x_var]], iris[[input$y_var]],
         xlab = input$x_var, ylab = input$y_var,
         main = "Scatter Plot")
    dev.off()
    
    plotURI <- base64enc::dataURI(file = plotfile, mime = "image/png")
    
    reportContent$items <- append(reportContent$items, list(
      list(type = "plot", content = plotURI, description = paste("Scatter Plot of", input$x_var, "vs", input$y_var))
    ))
    
    updateReportUI()
  })
  
  # Add table to the report
  observeEvent(input$add_table_to_report, {
    table_html <- datatable(iris, options = list(scrollX = TRUE)) %>% 
      as.character()  # Convert the DT object to HTML
    
    reportContent$items <- append(reportContent$items, list(
      list(type = "table", content = table_html, description = "Iris Data Table")
    ))
    
    updateReportUI()
  })
  
  # Add note to the report
  observeEvent(input$add_note_to_report, {
    note <- input$note_input
    if (note != "") {
      reportContent$items <- append(reportContent$items, list(
        list(type = "note", content = note, description = "Note")
      ))
      updateTextInput(session, "note_input", value = "")  # Clear input field after adding
      updateReportUI()
    }
  })
  
  # Update report content UI
  updateReportUI <- function() {
    output$report_content <- renderUI({
      items <- reportContent$items
      tagList(
        lapply(seq_along(items), function(i) {
          item <- items[[i]]
          if (item$type == "plot") {
            tagList(
              h3(item$description),
              img(src = item$content, height = "300px")
            )
          } else if (item$type == "table") {
            tagList(
              h3(item$description),
              HTML(item$content)  # Render the HTML table
            )
          } else if (item$type == "note") {
            tagList(
              h3(item$description),
              verbatimTextOutput(paste0("note_", i), placeholder = TRUE)
            )
          }
        })
      )
    })
    
    # Render notes in a separate output to maintain sequence
    lapply(seq_along(reportContent$items), function(i) {
      item <- reportContent$items[[i]]
      if (item$type == "note") {
        output[[paste0("note_", i)]] <- renderText({
          item$content
        })
      }
    })
  }
  
  # Enable download handler
  output$download_report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("report-", Sys.Date(), ".html", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      # Generate HTML content for download
      html_content <- tags$html(
        tags$head(
          tags$title("Dynamic Report")
        ),
        tags$body(
          h2("Report"),
          tagList(
            lapply(reportContent$items, function(item) {
              if (item$type == "plot") {
                tagList(
                  h3(item$description),
                  img(src = item$content, height = "300px")
                )
              } else if (item$type == "table") {
                tagList(
                  h3(item$description),
                  HTML(item$content)  # Render the HTML table
                )
              } else if (item$type == "note") {
                tagList(
                  h3(item$description),
                  pre(item$content)  # Use <pre> to display verbatim text
                )
              }
            })
          )
        )
      )
      
      # Save HTML content to file
      save_html(html_content, file)
    }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Short answer: yes.  It should be possible to get a screen grab of the current state tabPanel. You can definitely export the data that is displayed in the current tabPanel to a Word file, Rmd or Quarto report or export as csv or other data format.  At the moment, I feel your question is so vague it is likely to get closed for lack of detail or seeking recommendations.  Please make it both minimal and reproducible.  All the same, welcome to SO.

thank you very much for your help. i added a pretty much thrown together little script.
